# Trying to install lean in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command-prompt, lean

I got the following error and I don't know how to fix this issue.

```
m0nst3r@m0nst3r-G3:~/logical_verification_2019$ leanpkg configure
leanpkg: command not found
m0nst3r@m0nst3r-G3:~/logical_verification_2019$
```

kindly help with this. I tried pulling from the Github repository for my subject and I followed the following instructions from the git.

[The instructions for Linux is at the bottom when you scroll down](https://github.com/blanchette/logical_verification_2019)

Comment: Did you follow the instructions at https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/master/docs/install/debian.md? That's the recommended way to install on Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using ubuntu, install Lean using PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties # for add-apt-repository 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leanprover/lean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lean
```

Comment: This PPA provides Lean 2 only